# I made a function to convert an Int to a String, Advice, comments, etc :)

Tags: c++, string, int, concatenation, string-concatenation

Okay so I had a mini project and I came across the issue of having to convert an int to a string to be able to traverse through it like you would with any other string. I found some ways to do it online by including a library but I didn't really like them. I tried making my own function and wanted to know if this is decent.

As of now, it only takes in positive numbers and they should only be within the max int that C++ has to offer which is like 2 billion something.

Here it is:

```
// ONLY POSITIVE NUMBERS AND THEY MUST BE LESS THAN THE MAX INT
string castIntToString(int number){

    // find out how many numbers it has
    int numbers = 0;
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i/= 10){
        numbers++;
    }

    // generate the place value of the 1st number 
    int placeValue = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < numbers; i++){
        placeValue *= 10;
    }
    int modValue = placeValue * 10;

    // isolate each of those values
    // Why is "convertAscii" 48? Becuase character '0' is number 48
    int convertAscii = 48, actualValue;
    string numString = "";
    char actualCharValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
        actualValue = (number % (modValue)) / placeValue;
        actualCharValue = actualValue + convertAscii;
        numString+= actualCharValue;

        placeValue/= 10;
        modValue/= 10;
    }
    return numString;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with [std::to_string()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)? Also this may suit better on codereview.

Comment: Have you tried using it?

Comment: A lot of people don't realize how powerful the C++ standard library is.

Comment: I think you need a code review; head to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and yes, it's ok for learning but perhaps not so for production code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in one line by using [`sprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

```
char* str[10]; // The biggest possible int will take up to 10 char in base 10.
snprintf(str, 10, "%d", value); // where value is your int.
```

---

If you are using C++ 11 and it's `string`, [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a easier approach.

```
std::string str = to_string(value);
```

Comment: I think the asker just want to implement her own function.